# parsing XML in coldfusion

Tags: xslt, coldfusion, xml-parsing

I have an incoming XML package coming from a third party - 
they have provided an XSL to transform "part" of the package...

I need to 'extract' the node (w/ children) from the package using CF(10)

The package looks like this (reduced for size - btu can contain multiple 'data' nodes inside the main data node... luckily the main data node has an ID of a known string ("X_STUFF" in this example) - so I specifically want to grab that node w/ children...

```
<trip>
<eventTS>2012-09-19T14:54:42.0Z</eventTS>   
<eventX>0</eventX>
<eventY>10</eventY>
<eventType>driverRouteRequest</eventType>
<data id="X_STUFF">
    <datum name="A" value="..."/>
    <datum name="B" value="..."/>
    <data id="...">
        <datum name="a" value="0"/>
        <datum name="b" value="0"/>
        <datum name="c" value=""/>
    </data>
</data>
</trip>
```

If I try to transform the WHOLE package I get a 'zero-length' string error from the first node - the 'trip' node - or ANY node that doesn't have attributes - I don't know much about XSL - but it seems that way to me - I'll include the XSL here just for info - obviously, the "issue" could be solved by re-writing the XSL to accommodate nodes that are NOT the 'data' nodes (I didn't name them data/datum, sorry if that confuses things).. OR I can just pull the "main data" node w/ children...as I proposed above (this would be simpler, and more 'maintainable' form my perspective - at least until i can learn more about XSL)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="//*">
    <xsl:comment>Translated with datum-to-elements v1.0</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:element name="returnMessage">
        <xsl:call-template name="processChildren">
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="processChildren">
    <xsl:param name="branch"/>
    <xsl:variable name="AValue" select="./datum[@name='A']/@value" />
    <xsl:variable name="aValue" select="./datum[@name='a']/@value" />

    <xsl:variable name="newElementName">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($AValue) > 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$AValue"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$aValue"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="skipAttributeName">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($AValue) > 0">
                <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>a</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$newElementName}">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(child::*) > 0 ">
                    <xsl:call-template name="processChildren">
                        <xsl:with-param name="branch" select="child::*"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="@name != $skipAttributeName">
                        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="@value = 'y' or @value = 'Y'">true</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@value = 'n' or @value = 'N'">false</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? What do you need to do with this data? You could read this document into memory and then just parse it form there if you're just trying to get the structure or text content.

Comment: James - I need the document data from <data id="x_stuff'> ... </data>
"just parse it" is what I'm looking to do - however XMLSearch( myXML, '/trip/data' ) doesn't yield anything (yields an empty array).

Comment: @jpmyob - Try this `xmlSearch(myXML,"//*[@id='X_STUFF']")`

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfscript> 

myxmldoc = XmlParse("C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/test.xml"); 

myContent = XmlSearch(myxmldoc, "//*[@id='X_STUFF']"); 

writeDump(myContent);

</cfscript>
```

Credit to @Miguel-F for the xPath string too